# Solution of a quadratic form

Tags: number-theory

someone can help me to prove that $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=0$ has no trivial solution on $\mathbb{Q}_2$ i don't have a lot of ideas ($\mathbb{Q}_2$ is the 2-adic field).
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If there is a solution in $\mathbb Q_2$, you also have one in $\mathbb Z_2$.

First of all, I assume you have seen that $X^2+Y^2=0$ has no non-trivial solutions (*). This shows that a non-trivial solution of your equation must have all three variables non-zero.

Then by a standard argument, we can assume that not all three of $X,Y,Z$ are divisible by $2$: If so, divide by $2$ as often as possible and after finitely many divisions you end up with one variable being not divisible by $2$. (Here we need that all variables are non-zero!)

But considering the equation mod $4$, one easily sees that all three of $X,Y,Z$ must be divisible by $2$, contradiction!

---

If you haven't done (*), let me tell you that you can do it the exact same way: Consider it mod $4$.

Comment: For (*) is ok. To prove the assertion about the solution mod4 it suffice to analyse all the non trivial solution over it? There is any another reason?